# base64 string not opened video file after changing extension

Tags: ios, swift, base64

I am converting video file into base64 string and then using this base64 string to create text file. After creating text file, i changed their extension from .rtf to .mov
But this file not opened due to some problem.

This is the base64 string after converting from video file.

`AAAAIGZ0eXBxdCAgIAUDAHF0ICAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAId2lkZQAxyjRtZGF0 AAABsAEAAAG1iRMAAAEAAAABIADEiIAM4YoCHgoxAAABsjNpdnhApwAAAbYQ4JGD rbd422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jb b+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/ jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv42 2/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv 422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+N tv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb +Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/j bb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422 /jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv4 22/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Nt v422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+ Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jb b+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/ jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv42 2/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv 422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+N tv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb +Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/j bb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/jbb+Ntv422/`

[Error when open video file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wA9v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your final .mov file is a **base64 encoded** video file, not a video file.
You have to **base64 decode** its content to get the original video stream.